# How can I listen all incoming and outgoing data that goes to a Flash-base webchat?

Tags: flash, listen

I have a Flash-based webchat and I want to make chat aggregator. To make it I need to connect to a chat-server and to do that I have to know the format. That's why I have to listen flash session with a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a http debugging proxy such as Charles:
http://www.charlesproxy.com/

It will monitor all incoming and outgoing traffic on your computer. 
From there it will be pretty easy to check find the flash communication.

In a firefox browser you may also be able to use:
Tamper data
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

It does the same thing for firefox. Not sure if Tamper Data will capture socket info. But Charles will.